# How to use result set in JasperResports as data source?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, resultset

Here is a snippet of the JasperReport I developed that uses a static query embedded in the report.

```
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Report" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isFloatColumnFooter="true">
     <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
     <property name="ireport.x" value="129"/>
     <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
     <parameter name="lp" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
     <parameter name="all_price" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
     <parameter name="all_amount" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
     <parameter name="all_total_price" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
     <queryString>
          <![CDATA[SELECT sanaf_number,sanaf,sales_id,sales.sanaf_id,customer_name,  price, total_price, addad, wahda, required_amount FROM sanaf,sales  where (sales.export='0')and(sanaf.sanaf_id=sales.sanaf_id) limit $P{lp}]]>
     </queryString>
     <field name="sales_id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
     <field name="sanaf_id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
```

Now I need to use a `ResultSet` instead of a static query. The code I use to execute the report is below/

```
void showResports(){
  try{
    // OriginalExportOriginalExport 
    String reportName ="";

    if(export.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
      reportName = "OriginalExport.jasper";
    } else if(export.equalsIgnoreCase("0")){
      reportName = "ExportReport4.jasper";
    }

    InputStream in =getClass().getResourceAsStream(reportName);

    if(in==null|| connection==null) return ;

    HashMap parameterMap = new HashMap();
    parameterMap.put("lp", new Integer(selectedNumber));

    if(export.equalsIgnoreCase("0")){
      int all_price=DatabaseManager.countTotalPriceForImport(selectedNumber);
      int all_amount=DatabaseManager.countAmountForImport(selectedNumber);
      int all_total_price=DatabaseManager.countTotalPrice(selectedNumber);

      parameterMap.put("all_price",new Integer(all_price));
      parameterMap.put("all_amount",new Integer(all_amount));
      parameterMap.put("all_total_price",new Integer(all_total_price));
    } else if(export.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
      int all_requiredAmount=DatabaseManager.countAllRequiredAmount(selectedNumber);
      int all_given_amount=DatabaseManager.countAllGivenAmount(selectedNumber);
      parameterMap.put("all_requiredAmount",new Integer(all_requiredAmount));
      parameterMap.put("all_given_amount",new Integer(all_given_amount));
    }

    JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(in, parameterMap, connection);
    System.out.println("Object of Jasper Print created");

    JRViewer jv = new JRViewer(jp);
    //Insert viewer to a JFrame to make it showable
    JFrame jf = new JFrame();
    jf.getContentPane().add(jv);
    jf.validate();
    jf.setVisible(true);
    jf.setSize(new Dimension(800,600));
    jf.setLocation(300,100);
    jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);  
  }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}// showReports
```

Comment: You can view this [data source sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/datasource/index.html#datasources)

Answer (score 3):

If the result set contains the same fields as the query you currently have embedded in the report, then you need to remove the `queryString` from the report and then change:

```
JasperFillManager.fillReport(in, parameterMap, connection);
```

to

```
JasperFillManager.fillReport(in, parameterMap, new JRResultSetDataSource(resultSet));
```

where `resultSet` is the result set with the data.

The only complication that comes in is if the result set has different names for the fields, or different fields altogether. In which case you will need to adjust the field names in the report also.